# Trello Online indicators are gone

Tags: trello

We're not seeing online indicators in Trello anymore and I can't find mention of this anywhere as an official change.  Is anyone else noticing this? Is this a known change I just haven't found mention of?

Comment: They're back again. So they worked hard and fixed it I guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The team has temporarily disabled after experiencing some technical issues. They will be back in the future, but it's not known when.

Comment: Any update on when this could be back? For distributed teams this was a really nice feature.

Comment: @Ostemar We are working on a smarter "presence" service for online status. We don't have a time estimate for when they'll be back, though.